# Apple TV Screen Mirroring not working from iPad

Tags: ipad, appletv, airplay, screen-sharing

Every time I select Screen Mirroring from the Control Center and select my Apple TV from the list, it shows that the screen is being mirrored to my TV (there is a checkmark next to the name of the Apple TV), but nothing happens on the Apple TV. I tried restarting the Apple TV and the iPad, disabling/re-enabling Bluetooth/Wi-Fi on the iPad and AirPlay/Screen Mirroring, nothing helped. What can I do to make Screen Mirroring work again?

Comment: make sure that your AppleTV and iPad are updated to the latest OS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Tap on **Control Center/Screen Mirroring/Stop Mirroring** on the iPad.
2. **Rename your Apple TV** by navigating to **Settings/General/About/Name**.
3. Try mirroring your iPad's screen again, it should work.
4. Optionally, you can change your Apple TV's name back to the original name.